# MYSQL TRIGGER AFTER DELETE not UPDATING

Tags: mysql, triggers

Iam trying to create a Trigger that works after a delete...

I have two tables..

```
**despatchitems**
id|solditems_id|quantity
```

Another...

```
**solditems**
id|despatched|quantity
```

Below is the trigger i wrote

```
  CREATE TRIGGER `del_despatch_solditems` AFTER DELETE ON `despatchitems`
   FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    Declare sum int;
    SELECT SUM(`quantity`) INTO sum FROM despatchitems WHERE solditems_id=old.solditems_id;
    UPDATE solditems SET despatched=sum WHERE id=old.solditems_id;
   END
```

What this trigger is supposed to do is update the despatched column in the "solditems" table once there is a delete in the "despatchitems" table. 
The same trigger is working in case of an UPDATE OR INSERT...below is code

```
CREATE TRIGGER `ins_despatched_solditems` AFTER INSERT ON `despatchitems`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  Declare sum int;
  SELECT SUM(`quantity`) INTO sum FROM despatchitems WHERE solditems_id=NEW.solditems_id;
  UPDATE solditems SET despatched=sum WHERE id= NEW.solditems_id;
END
CREATE TRIGGER `upd_despatched_solditems` AFTER UPDATE ON `despatchitems`
 FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  Declare sum int;
  SELECT SUM(`quantity`) INTO sum FROM despatchitems WHERE solditems_id=NEW.solditems_id;
  UPDATE solditems SET despatched=sum WHERE id= NEW.solditems_id;
END
```

For reasons i cant figure out the AFTER DELETE trigger is not working. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: UPDATE solditems SET despatched=sum WHERE id=old.solditems_id; Are you sure you want to use old.solditems_id?

Comment: Yes please I would like to use old.solditems_id

Comment: You deleted records. Then you query for those records. You get a zero. Your trigger is after delete - it should be before delete. `SELECT SUM(quantity) INTO sum FROM despatchitems WHERE solditems_id=old.solditems_id;` -> won't work. You have nothing in `despatchitems`. You deleted it.

Comment: Ive tried BEFORE DELETE as well...still does not work...